# Weird characters (�) in JSON written by PHP to file

Tags: javascript, php, json, encoding, utf-8

I have a PHP code which writes a JSON file when it's called. The file contains a few latin characters from spanish and portuguese language. It is displayed correctly on the browser when browsing it directly to it's URL, but in the application and in the developer console under the response preview tab, these characters are replaced by the character �.

Picture to better explain the situation:
[image: bad characters]
*(Click picture to open in full size)*

The file is written in PHP with the following code:

```
file_put_contents('../data/cameras.json', $json, LOCK_EX);
```

I tried many ways to fix this encoding with no success (some of them even removed the characters, but that's not an acceptable solution).

Any suggestions of how to solve this problem?

Comment: How exactly are you producing `$json`?

Comment: Can you post the response headers from the developer console and the original file stored in the server by the PHP code?

Comment: The information is being read from a Postgre database (which I don't know it's encoding) and sanitized by `str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "", (str_replace('"', "'", trim($string))));`. The file is located at http://www.seventh.com.br/calculadora2-testing/data/cameras.json

Comment: So, are you using `json_encode`, or are you manually cobbling the JSON together?

Comment: No, in this case I'm not using `json_encode`.

Comment: 1) Establish the connection to the database using UTF-8, 2) create your data structure as PHP arrays, 3) output to JSON using `json_encode`. Then your encoding problems will be solved. Currently your JSON is likely invalid since it's not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Well, the fact is that browser manages to show it correctly, but dev console and debugger show invalid characters. Maybe it is about server not sending character encoding in the response header? Would defining encoding in the response header help? That is: ``Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8``.

Comment: @deceze The problem is that the connection to the database is managed by another PHP file imported by many other components of the website. I'm checking this file and it's not specified as UTF-8, but if I will change it, chances are I will break many other parts of the website.

Comment: Then fetch the data in whatever encoding you're getting it (figure out what that is), and convert it to UTF-8 manually using `iconv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded the json-file and when looking at it in notepad++ in `ANSI` mode, it looks fine. So i guess the file is in `WINDOWS-1252` encoding.
And i am guessing that you want to use `UTF8` in the file you write with PHP.

try to convert the encoding of your string before you write the file:

```
$json = mb_convert_encoding($json, "UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252");

file_put_contents('../data/cameras.json', $json, LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: This works. For some reason, browsing directly to the file shows wrong characters, but in the application and in the response tab, it looks fine. I know something is improperly configured (as browsing should also show the content correctly), but that's a problem for later, the application is working. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The most common problem is that your .json file is not saved as UTF-8. Open the file with notepad, and save it as UTF-8. Also make sure your PHP file is UTF-8.

Comment: This is unviable, this file is generated automatically every now and then (as stated in the question). I can't be waiting for it to be generated and then re-convert it manually every time it is.

Comment: Should pay more attention to the question next time, only after I've posted an answer I realized the file is generated.